# How do I change the value of a variable from another class and still be able to change it within the other class?

Tags: java

So I'm fairly new with programming having done it for maybe just under a year at this point. I'm even more new with Java (I did C++ before). So I have variables like numberHealthPotions, health, attackDamage, and so on, in a class named Fighting. But then in my main class, there are points in the game in which the character picks up a weapon, picks up a potion, or is wounded. I just need a way to say in my main class he was wounded then change the value of the health of the character or whatever.

This is just a snipet of my code to give you an idea...

```
else if(inputHKitchen.equalsIgnoreCase ("examine")){
                System.out.println("Examine what?");
                examineWhat = in.nextLine();
                if(examineWhat.equalsIgnoreCase("drawer")){
                    System.out.println("\tYou found a knife!");
                    attackDamage = 50;
                    System.out.println("\tYour attack damage has been increased!\n");
                    System.out.println(houseKitchen);
                }
```

Comment: If you have `setter` methods in your `Fighting` class, then you can use those to set the values.

Answer (score 1):

If your variable is static, then it might be

```
//note this variable must be public or protected
Player.HEALTH = 0;
```

if its not static, then

```
Player p = new Player();
p.HEALTH = 0;
```

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you mean by this.. Like I said I'm pretty new to programming, especially in java..

Comment: You can reference a variable from another class, Inside your Main class, you could reference a Player object(class) representing one of the players in your game. For example, if you haven't done so already, create a Player class, and create variables like numberHealthPotions, health, attackdamage and so on. Then, you can change their value from inside your main class, by using ways shown in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a series of public methods for the character that manage these various values.

For example, in the class YourCharacter:

```
private int attackDamage;

public void addDamage(int value)
{
    attackDamage += value;
}
```

Then in your snippet:

```
if (examineWhat.equalsIgnoreCase("drawer")){
    yourCharacter.addDamage(50);
}
```

Lots of good game-writing advice for Java can be found at [java-gaming.org](http://java-gaming.org)